# SignalR Not Working with Windows Auth

Tags: windows, authentication, signalr

I've created a test MVC5 application to run the simple SignalR chat client shown here and everything worked as the tutorial described.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

I've then created another project where I enable Windows Authentication and my messages are not being received by the chat clients. However, my message requests are hitting the "ChatHub" Send method but my chat clients are not receiving the messages.  Everything is identical to the original tutorial except for adding Windows Authentication. Any ideas what could be my problem?  Thanks in advance.

jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a user error. I jumped between the original SignalR tutorial and SignalR with MVC5 tutorial and ran into a discrepancy. Original SignalR tutorial had  chat.client.addNewMessageToPage" and the SignalR with MVC5 tutorial "chat.client.broadcastMessage" and I must have botched the copy and paste job between projects and tutorials. Feeling a little sheepish at the moment.